# Copying value from file geodatabase field into shapefile field using ModelBuilder?

Tags: shapefile, modelbuilder

Does anyone know how I can pass the value from a field in a file geodatabase to a field in a shapefile using ModelBuilder?

I have a Model to do a Definition query via the Select, then use Summary Statistics to SUM a column and write it to a file geodatabase table. I now need to take this table field value and write it to a shapefile field.

Comment: Which model builder (QGIS, ArcGIS and version) are you using?

Comment: @TrevorJ.Smith I suspect it must be ArcGIS Desktop because of the term ModelBuilder being used.  For similar functionality in QGIS the term QGIS Modeler seems to be used by most.  In any event I think we need to see a picture of their model so far, and text to say whether it is the ModelBuilder of ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, or the QGIS Modeler that is being used.

Comment: I'm using ArcMap Model Builder. I have a Shapefile and I use Summary Statistics in the Model to get the value I need: 'SUM'. But Summery Statistics writes the value 'SUM' to a file geodatabase. I need to take this value and write it to a Shapefile field.